# ListView scroll up for refresh, scroll down to add new items to the list

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

Right now I have a Listview that stores 25 items, which are retrieved from an API. What I want is that the ListView refreshes on scroll up (retreive data from api call again). And add another 25 items on scroll down.

What could I use for this?
I found SwipeRefreshLayout, However, I can't find a way to distinguish scroll up and scroll down.

Comment: For load more items check https://codentrick.com/load-more-recyclerview-bottom-progressbar/

Comment: Same question and also have an answer : [pull to refresh and loadmore listview like facebook [closed]
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362732/pull-to-refresh-and-loadmore-listview-like-facebook)

Comment: You should use pagination here. Try RecyclerView instead of ListView and add OnPageScrollListener, whenever the page get scrolled, you will need to call the api again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListVIew`. Initialize the `RecyclerView` as follows :

**RecyclerView Initialization :**

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
videosAdapter = new VideosAdapter();
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInUpAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(videosAdapter);

// Pagination
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewOnScrollListener);
```

Now setup `OnScrollListener` :

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewOnScrollListener = new 
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                && totalItemCount >= PAGE_SIZE) {
            loadMoreItems();
        }
    }
}
};
```

Once you get the response you need to add the received data to the list again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is little bit misleading.If i am not wrong, here can be to thing.

1. **Reload List on Over Scroll Down** :- This functionality can be achieve by using [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html). Follow the android tutorial for [Adding Swipe-to-Refresh To Your App](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html).
2. **Load more items on Over Scroll Up**:- This is the part of Lay loading(Pagination) . If you are using `ListView`then you can use `OnScrollListener` and `setFooterView()` to make it done . Have a look at [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762878/pagination-listview-in-large-data-loading-in-android).

**Suggestion:-** A simple suggestion Use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` to make better use of `ViewHolder` pattern.

Comment: I can't seem to use new OnScrollListener in C# what i'm missing?